# ebproof in a tabular environment?

Tags: tables

When trying to compile the simple document:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebproof}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c c c }
    \begin{prooftree*}
        \infer{0}{foo}
    \end{prooftree*}
    &
    \begin{prooftree*}
        \infer{0}{bar}
    \end{prooftree*}
    &
    \begin{prooftree*}
        \infer{0}{baz}
    \end{prooftree*}
    \\
    \begin{prooftree*}
        \infer{0}{foo}
    \end{prooftree*}
    &
    \begin{prooftree*}
        \infer{0}{bar}
    \end{prooftree*}
    &
    \begin{prooftree*}
        \infer{0}{baz}
    \end{prooftree*}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I get the error:

```
! Argument of \ebproof_statement_parse:w has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.9             \infer{0}{foo}
```

I didn't see anything mentioning a tabular environment breaking in the documentation for ebproof, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `prooftree*` environment is more a less a display math environment. So you shouldn't use it in a c-column.

Also `ebproof` uses  `&` to align text blocks. This means that it can get confused by the `&` from the tabular. Surround the environment by braces to protect them:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebproof}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{ ccc} %e.g. p{4cm} p{4cm} p{4cm}} for prooftree*
    {\begin{prooftree}
        \infer{0}{foo}
    \end{prooftree}}
    &
    {\begin{prooftree}
        \infer{0}{bar}
    \end{prooftree}}
    &
    {\begin{prooftree}
        \infer{0}{baz}
    \end{prooftree}}
    \\\relax
    {\begin{prooftree}
        \infer{0}{foo}
    \end{prooftree}}
    &
    {\begin{prooftree}
        \infer{0}{bar}
    \end{prooftree}}
    &
    {\begin{prooftree}
        \infer{0}{baz}
    \end{prooftree}}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `prooftree*`, because it essentially does

```
\[
<proof tree>
\]
```

which is not legal in a `tabular` cell.

So you have to use `prooftree`, but there's another issue: braces are necessary, unless you slightly change the definition.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebproof}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentEnvironment { prooftree } { s O{} } {
  \group_align_safe_begin:
  \keys_set_known:nnN { ebproof / proof~style } { #2 } \l_tmpa_tl
  \keys_set:nV { ebproof } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_set:Nx \l_ebproof_start_level_tl { \int_use:N \g_ebproof_level_int }
  \vbox_set:Nw \l_tmpa_box
  \ebproof_setup_statements:
} {
  \vbox_set_end:
  \ebproof_pop:N \l_ebproof_a_box
  \int_compare:nNnF { \g_ebproof_level_int } = { \tl_use:N \l_ebproof_start_level_tl } {
    \PackageError{ebproof}{Malformed~proof~tree}{
      Some~hypotheses~were~declared~but~not~used~in~this~tree.}
  }
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 } {
    \[ \box_use:N \l_ebproof_a_box \]
    \ignorespacesafterend
  } {
    \hbox_unpack:N \c_empty_box
    \bool_if:NTF \l_ebproof_center_bool {
      \hbox:n { $ \tex_vcenter:D { \box_use:N \l_ebproof_a_box } $ }
    } {
      \box_use:N \l_ebproof_a_box
    }
  }
  \group_align_safe_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ |c| }
\hline
\begin{prooftree}
  \hypo{ \Gamma, A &\vdash B }
  \infer1[abs]{ \Gamma &\vdash A\to B }
  \hypo{ \Gamma \vdash A }
  \infer2[app]{ \Gamma \vdash B }
\end{prooftree}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{prooftree}
  \hypo{ \Gamma, A &\vdash B }
  \infer1[abs]{ \Gamma &\vdash A\to B }
  \hypo{ \Gamma \vdash A }
  \infer2[app]{ \Gamma \vdash B }
\end{prooftree}
\begin{prooftree*}
  \hypo{ \Gamma, A &\vdash B }
  \infer1[abs]{ \Gamma &\vdash A\to B }
  \hypo{ \Gamma \vdash A }
  \infer2[app]{ \Gamma \vdash B }
\end{prooftree*}

\end{document}
```

The changes to the original are the addition of

```
\group_align_safe_begin:
```

at the beginning and of

```
\group_align_safe_end:
```

at the end. You may want to make this known to the package author.

In the example I use the environment in a `tabular` and outside of it; I also show what `prooftree*` does.

[image]